# How to see python docs for opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

Cant find python documentation for opencv.

I am using python and try to do some denoising using opencv as in this tutorial:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html

However,  when I want to check the parameters to the function and click on for example "cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising" I come to the documentation for the C++-implementation. How can I find the python documentation?!

Comment: `help(cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising)`

Comment: Yeah thanks, but if you follow an link to a python function, you should be able to see the python parameters.

Comment: It is perplexing how great a library opencv is, but how far behind they are in terms of Q/A and documentation standards.

Answer (score 10):

## Edit - November 10, 2021

[The most recent version of the OpenCV docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/) (4.5.4 at the time of this writing) has the Python signatures directly below the C++ signatures.  For your specific case, the function you are interested in can be found here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d1/d79/group__photo__denoise.html#ga4c6b0031f56ea3f98f768881279ffe93

---

## Outdated (here for posterity)

OpenCV 3.0 beta docs are the last known stable docs for the Python functions. Unfortunately, anything after they don't show you the equivalent calls between C++ and Python.  I use these as a guide, but take them with a grain of salt.

For your specific case: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/photo/doc/denoising.html?highlight=denoising#fastnlmeansdenoising