# What is the meaning of 'flag' in cv2.imdecode?

Tags: python, opencv

```
image_np = cv2.imdecode(img_arr, -1)
```

What is the meaning of the `flag` argument in `cv2.imdecode`?

I don't understand what the '-1' represents.

Comment: In case, cv refers to opencv module, refer to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-imdecode-function/ for understanding what flag is in `cv2.imdecode(...)`.

Answer (score 7):

The flag in imdecode method specifies - How the image should be read.
Flag can take values 1,0,-1 etc.

1 specifies cv2.IMREAD_COLOR : Reads image in BGR color format and removes the alpha channel .It is the default value of flag.

0 specifies cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE : Reads image in grayscale.

-1 specifies cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED  : Reads image without change, preserves the alpha channel

Answer (score 0):

The actual documentation for these flags is [the `ImreadModes` documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80); the [`imdecode` documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e) mentions that they use the same flags. You have to click through to the [actual enumeration (HPP link)](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d6/d87/imgcodecs_8hpp.html) to see that -1 is [`cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80aeddd67043ed0df14f9d9a4e66d2b0708) (it's considered bad practice to use the magical constant instead of the symbolic value, but these things happen).

> If set, return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel, otherwise it gets cropped).
> Ignore EXIF orientation.

Perhaps see also [How to see python docs for opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304657/how-to-see-python-docs-for-opencv)